# ios app does not show the data in the tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I followed the tutorial here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iOS_4_iPhone_Table_View_Application but for some reason, all i get is the white screen. The table does not even show.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

I have added this line to show the view

```
[window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

So i am sure that the table should be visible.

Comment: you should post more code if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: did you do anything differently from the tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `self.viewController` assigned?  If you are putting it in a nib, did you hook up the `IBOutlet`?  What does `NSLog(@"%@", self.viewController");` say?

Comment: and this is the IBOutlet 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet tableshow1ViewController *viewController;